# Here iOS SDK Label Map Marker

Tags: ios, here-api

I am using the Here iOS SDK. I am attempting to add a label marker to my map.

According to the the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-starter/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapMarker.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAMapMarker(im)showInfoBubble) I can use a NMAMapMarker and set the title and textDescription properties. But these properties do not exist in the class header file. Is the documentation incorrect? How do I add a label marker?

Comment: Which version of the Here iOS SDK are you using? The documentation is related to Starter Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-starter/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapMarker.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAMapMarker(im)showInfoBubble) you are referencing is for HERE **Starter** SDK. Indeed, it contains *title* and *textDescription* properties of *NMAMapMarker*.

For HERE **Premium** SDK documentation please follow the [link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapMarker.html).

Instead of *NMAMapMarker*, take a look at [NMAMapOverlay](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapOverlay.html)